# R Shiny rCharts Morris - rChart is not displaying (under particular circumstances)

Tags: r, plot, shiny, rcharts, morris.js

I came across a problem while using `rCharts` in my `Shiny` application. I generate dynamically 1-3 `tabPanels` (depending on the user selection) and in each of them one plot is rendered. Plot may be of two types: simple (with *graphics* libary) or rCharts (with ***morris* library**). The whole `tabsetPanel` is rendered within the `uiOutput` component, each time an user changes his input. The type of the `ui output` (`plotOutput` for simple plot or `showOutput` for rCharts) is defined when a `tabPanel` is rendered, so the plot **does** have a *proper* environment.

And the **problem**: simple plots (with graphics, ggplot2 etc.) do work OK - they are displayed correctly in a `tabPanel`. However, when I work with application and have 2 or 3 rCharts to be displayed, it happens that **one chart is not displaying** - almost at all (see the images below). Of course, such a problem does not appear with simple plots.

I tried to have the output size fixed, size flexible, but the problem still exists. I have varsions of R and the libraries as follows:

```
> R.Version()$version.string
[1] "R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)"
> packageVersion("Shiny")
[1] ‘0.7.0’
> packageVersion("rCharts")
[1] ‘0.3.51’
```

Thank you a lot for any suggestions.

**rCharts working OK:**

[image]

**rCharts FAIL to be dispkayed ok:**

[image]

**EDIT:** my code below:

**UI**

```
library(shiny)
library(Epi)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(  
  headerPanel("Header"),  

  sidebarPanel(        
    checkboxInput(inputId = "checkboxInputx", label = "function: x", value = TRUE),
    checkboxInput(inputId = "checkboxInputxpower2", label = "function: x^2", value =     FALSE),
    checkboxInput(inputId = "checkboxInput2x", label = "function:  2x", value = FALSE),

    actionButton("gobutton","GO!")
   ),

  mainPanel(    
    radioButtons("plottypechoice", "Choose plot type", c("simple", "rCharts")),    
    uiOutput("plotpanelcontent")
  )   
))
```

**SERVER**

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(Epi)
library(reshape2)

# build data frame 
x <- 1:100
df <- data.frame(x, x^2, 2*x)
names(df) <- c("x", "xpower2", "2productx")


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # generate tabsetPanel with tabPlots with plot of selected type 
  output$plotpanelcontent <- renderUI({ 

    if(input$gobutton != 0){


        # collect tab names 
        tab.names <- vector()
        if(input$checkboxInputx) tab.names <- c(tab.names, "x")
        if(input$checkboxInputxpower2) tab.names <- c(tab.names, "xpower2")
        if(input$checkboxInput2x) tab.names <- c(tab.names, "2productx")
        print(tab.names)

        # render tabs
        tabs <- lapply(tab.names, function(tab.name){ 
          # define tabPanel content depending on plot type selection 
          if(input$plottypechoice == "simple")
            tab <- tabPanel(tab.name, plotOutput(paste0("simpleplot", tab.name)))
          else
            tab <- tabPanel(tab.name, showOutput(paste0("rchartplot", tab.name), "morris"))
          return(tab)
        })  
        return(do.call(tabsetPanel, tabs))
    }
  })  


  # Render simple plots 
  output$simpleplotx <- renderPlot({ 
    print(plot(df[,1], df[,1]))
    plot(df[,1], df[,1]) 
  })
  output$simpleplotxpower2 <- renderPlot({ 
    print(plot(df[,1], df[,2]))
    plot(df[,1], df[,2])   
  })
  output$simpleplot2productx <- renderPlot({ 
    print(plot(df[,1], df[,3]))
    plot(df[,1], df[,3])   
  })


  # Render rCharts 
  output$rchartplotx <- renderChart({ 
    plot <- mPlot(x="x", y="x", type = "Line", data = df)
    plot$set(dom = "rchartplotx")
    return(plot)
  })
  output$rchartplotxpower2 <- renderChart({ 
    plot <- mPlot(x="x", y="xpower2", type = "Line", data = df)
    plot$set(dom = "rchartplotxpower2")
    return(plot)
  })
  output$rchartplot2productx <- renderChart({ 
    plot <- mPlot(x="x", y="2productx", type = "Line", data = df)
    plot$set(dom = "rchartplot2productx")
    return(plot)
  })
})
```

**UPDATE:**

I have asked [Olly Smith](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/), an author of morris.js library, to suggest a solution and I received a following response:

*Morris can't correctly draw charts when they're not displayed on screen. When using Morris in tabbed applications, you need to redraw the active chart whenever the tab selection changes. There's a redraw() method on the chart objects that each of the Morris.Line/Bar/Donut constructors return that you can use to do this. Unfortunately, it's currently undocumented, but it's a stable part of the API now so it's safe to use.*

**UPDATE 2. :**

I followed the **Ramnath** suggestions and update both `Shiny` and `rCharts` libraries version:

```
> packageVersion("Shiny")
[1] ‘0.8.0’
>  packageVersion("rCharts")
[1] ‘0.3.53’
```

and run the code just after restarting the R session. Unfortunately, plots seem to behave in even stranger way now. After doing actions in the following order:

1. set: "function: x", "rCharts", GO [OK],
2. add: "function: x^2" [see "not_ok_1" image attached below in the post],
3. add: "function: 2x" [see "not_ok_2" image attached below  in the post].

I received the plot visualizations as follows:

1. **OK**
   [image]
2. **"not_ok_1" image**
   [image]
3. **"not_ok_2" image**
   [image]

Comment: Show your code so that we can see how it differs from a working example such as [this one](http://ramnathv.github.io/rChartsShiny/)

Comment: Code supplied! Thank you for your interest, **GSee**.

Comment: Try updating shiny.  Your code worked for me with the same version of R, but with shiny 0.8.0 (I also have an old version of rCharts installed)

Comment: **GSee**, I followed your suggestion (getting `packageVersion("shiny") [1] ‘0.8.0’`) and the problem is not solved. As I mention, it takes place not every time, but under some circumstances (after some user input and action combinations). For example, **please try do actions in such an order**: 

1. 
set: "function: x", plot: "simple" [OK] 

2. 
change plot to: "rCharts" [OK] 

3. 
add function: "function: 2x" [see both 2 tabPanels are displayed OK]

4. 
add function: "function: x^2" [see: 2 tabPanels ("x", "xpower2") OK, but tabPabpanel "2productx" is not displayed correctly !!! ]

Comment: Please note I have updated the post with the suggestion of author of morris.js library.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me with Shiny 0.8.0. rCharts redraws the entire chart every time `renderChart` is invoked, so you should not run into this particular problem. Can you update `rCharts` to 0.3.53 (`devtool::install_github("rCharts", "ramnathv", ref = "dev")`) and also update your Shiny version?

Comment: **Ramnath**, thank you a lot for your attention and this suggestion! Unfortunately, it did not do the trick in my application :( I attached an *Update 2.* to this post - you can see the strange results I received.

Comment: Okay. This is exactly what I got as well, so at least we are on the same page now :) The good thing is that the plots are showing up. I will investigate the reason behind the weirdness in the x-y ranges.

Comment: Thank you, **Ramnath**! I am looking forward to hearing any further suggestions. What I did today was excluding the possibility it is caused by re-rendering the `tabsetPanel` (thus `tabPanels` and `showOutput` too) over and over - I implemented `Conditional Tab Panels` (as proposed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/7kLFhrXPyQY))  so as to have `tabPanels` (and so the `rCharts` objects) be rendered ONLY one time - and the plots were displayed in EXACTLY the same bad way.